# SVN Update via Web form on Windows & Linux machine

Tags: php, svn

I have been working some time on this and I can't find the solution ( if there is any ).

So the question: **Is there a way to do an `svn update` request via HTML web form?**

I have tested multiple web-based SVN clients ( including building my own ), but they all lack the possibility to do an update.

I understand that this is an issue with the user permission that PHP uses, but even if I set all files on my system to `777` ( tried it on a virtual machine ), there still is no way I can archive it.

Anyone has some experience on this?

Thank you already.

I also went over all the directories and set owner to `Everyone` with full access. Now there can't be a permission issue ... I think.

*Last edit:*
It seems I can't execute the SVN if the script file is not in the root directory of the svn directory. The final code now looks like this: http://codepad.org/Kb2K8e6m

Comment: From a comment you posted below: *"I don't need it to be default up-to-date. I want the possibility to update my site to any revision at any time and only when I need it."* If this is the case, then the form and the SVN working copy should have all the same permissions, given that they're both being accessed by the Apache user, no? Unless you didn't set the proper owner on the files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following function should more or less do it for you. It also prints out:

1. The exact command it is executing in shell
2. The output of the command (including errors) so that it can also be debugged.

---

```
function updatesvn() {

    if ( isset($_POST) ) {

        //Get svn username and password from request parameters

        $username = <your_svn_username>;
        $password = <your_svn_password>;

        //Get version number to move to
        $values = $_POST;
        $version = $values['revision'];

        //validate version number

        //Path where you have checked out your project
        $rpath = '/var/www/myproj';

        //Command to svn update
        $cmd = "cd $rpath; svn cleanup; svn --non-interactive --username $username --password $password update -r $version 2>&1";

        echo $cmd;
        $out = shell_exec($cmd);

        echo $out;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Beware of security loopholes in this code. I have simplified it here. We had used it in one of our applications where a user reaching this point was pre-authenticated as an `Admin` user of the web application. In addition this code was executed in an MVC framework where validations on input were done in central places before executing an action in a controller.

Comment: you are passing user input directly to the PHP command line! Your script doesn't validate the user input and allows for a user to execute *any* command on the server.

Comment: @OzairKafray Ok, I finally had some time to test this: `cd c:\data\mysite.com\;svn cleanup; svn --non-interactive --username --password update -r 6` gives me `The system cannot find the path specified.`

Comment: Ok, I edited the line. It works perfect, when I execute it on CLI, but it gives no output and does nothing when run in `test.php` site as a php script. This is how it looks currently: http://i49.tinypic.com/288obis.png

Comment: @DainisAbols If username and password fileds are empty as I see in attached code please remove the --username and --password strings altogether.

Comment: I just deleted the info before posting :) There is a password and a username.

Comment: @DainisAbols: I have modified a few parts of the code. This version will echo 1. The exact `cmd` and 2. The output of the command. This should help you get there.

Comment: I'm back an still stuck. I added an `svnversion` check before execution and it also gives me nothing. What trivial think am I doing wrong? This is how the code look right now: http://codepad.org/Yfp4uXqW

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Make sure that the user apache OR www-data own the repository folder

Comment: None at all:
php-errors.log = `silent`
access.log = `127.0.0.1 - - [07/Aug/2012:17:46:37 +0300] "GET /test/test.php?revision=6 HTTP/1.1" 200 88`
error.log = `silent`

Comment: @OzairKafray remember that I'm doing this on a Windows machine.

Comment: Ok, it works now. I moved the file `test/test.php` to just `test.php` and executed only `svn --non-interactive update -r $version`. Did not work w/ cleanup and dir change. Well, not the best solution, but at least a working one.

Comment: I saw the updated code. Can you check if it works if you keep the `2>&1` part in $cmd also, instead of appending it in `exec` function.

Comment: @OzairKafray It should work. There is no difference when I add it. I just took the debug code from another script, that's why it's not included in `$cmd` part.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [svn_update()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.svn-update.php) from the PECL svn extension (or [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) and command-line svn - there is actually not much difference).

The solution I prefer for permission problems is to set umask `002` for all users who will update (including `www-data` or whatever your webserver user is), put them into a common `phpuser` group, set that group for the root directory of the working copy (`chgrp phpuser <rootdir>` - *before* the checkout!), make sure it is group writable (`chmod g+rwx <rootdir>`) and set it to setgid (`chmod g+s <rootdir>`), but if you don't care about preserving file permissions, then certainly `chmod -R 777 <rootdir>` is much simpler.

Comment: 1.Not sure I want to use something that has this written: "This function is EXPERIMENTAL. The behaviour of this function, its name, and surrounding documentation may change without notice in a future release of PHP. This function should be used at your own risk."
2. AS I said already, the permissions are set to `Everyone` w/ full access.

Comment: @DainisAbols: I have used SVN:PHP without any problems. If I need to do slight changes next time I update PHP (typically happens once or twice a year), I can live with that. I would not use it in production, but then I can't imagine why I would call SVN from production code in the first place. As for permissions, granting all rights to everyone is not that good (it is insecure and it might mess up the permission flags stored in SVN if you use the working copy for commits), so I tried to explain how you can do better. Of course that is only relevant once you solve your original problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you building a continuous integration server?  Why would you want to let any Joe Bloggs update your local repository?

You'd have to have some code on the back end to execute the "svn update" in a shell.

Generally, a web-based SVN client would feed directly into the SVN repository and would by default be up-to-date - it should even let you view previous versions and diffs.

Comment: I don't need it to be default up-to-date. I want the possibility to update my site to any revision at any time and **only** when I need it.